# Вывод структуры объекта списком JS

Tags: javascript

Имеется скрипт на js:

```
var user = new Object();
      user.date = new Object();
      user.pref = new Object();
      user.log = new Object();

      user.date.name = "name";
      user.date.ip = "ip";
      user.date.login = "login";

      user .pref.prefName = "prefName";

      user.log.username = "username";
      user.log.time = "time";
      user.log.mac = "mac";

      document.write("<ul>");
        for(objItem in user){
          document.write("<li>"+objItem+"</li>");
          document.write("<ul>");
          for(itemLevel1 in objItem){
              document.write("<li>"+itemLevel1+"</li>");
          }
          document.write("</ul>");
        }
      document.write("</ul>");
```

Нужно чтобы он вывод структуру объекта user в виде вложенных списков. Это учебный пример. Вывод только поля верхнего уровня, вот пример вывода.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кто знает что не так?

Comment: А, ну и плюс к дубликату: _objItem_ - это строка.

Comment: поэтому ее ключи - это индексы символов

Answer (score 0):

```js
var user = {
  date: {
    name: 'name',
    ip: 'ip',
    login: 'login'
  },
  pref: {
    prefName: 'prefName'
  },
  log: {
    username: 'username',
    time: 'time',
    mac: 'mac'
  }
};

var list = document.createElement('ul');
document.getElementById('listwrap').appendChild(list);
writeList(user, list);

function writeList(obj, parentUl) {
  for(var prop in obj) {
    var item = obj[prop];
    var itemEl = document.createElement('li');
    parentUl.appendChild(itemEl);

    if(typeof item == 'object') {
      itemEl.innerHTML = prop;
      var listInner = document.createElement('ul');
      parentUl.appendChild(listInner);
      
      writeList(item, listInner);
    } else {
      itemEl.innerHTML = prop +': '+ item;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="listwrap"></div>
```